# Why isn't my catch block not works while passing LINUX command in email?

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework2, try-catch

I have some code that looks like this

```
  try
  {
    $emailObj->checkEmailExist($emailid);
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    echo 'Insert Record.';
    $emailObj->addEmail($emailid);
  }

  static function checkEmailExist($emailID)
  {
    $rowset = $this->_tableGateway->select(array('user_email_id'=>$emailID));
    $row = $rowset->current();
  }
  if (!$row) {
    throw new \Exception("Could not find data for email : $emailID",404);
  }     
  return $row;
}
```

now when i passing email that contains any LINUX commands like **scp, rcp, ssh** then catch block not executed

if i passed email like

- **test@gmail.com**

> it check if exist or not, if not then insert email

if I passed email like

- **ssh.test@gmail.com**

> it stops execution with throw an exception, even email not exist -
>   Insert function not executed.

I am not sure why catch block not getting worked with LINUX commands in email? 
Please help...

Comment: Where is the class deceleration, is it namespaced?  this `throw new \Exception` leads me to think it is. if it is you need to do the same for the Exception class you are catching or it looks for `namespace/Exception`

Answer (score 0):

I think probably your class is namespaced, if so you need to root out the Exception class you are catching for:

```
try
{
     $emailObj->checkEmailExist($emailid);
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Insert Record.';
    $emailObj->addEmail($emailid);
}
```

By adding `\` in front of it, or it looks for `namespace\Exception` by default.

I'm just guessing that based on how you throw the exception

```
throw new \Exception("Could not find data for email : $emailID",404);
```

You wouldn't need to use `\Exception` if your class wasn't namespaced.  You could do `Exception` instead.

Cheers!

One last thing, the code you put is totally invalid:

```
  try{ 
   ...
  }

  static function checkEmailExist(){
  ...
  }
```

To me this says:

```
 <?php
   namespace somename;
  class someclass{


        try{ 
         ...
        }

        static function checkEmailExist(){
        ...
        }


 }
```

In which place you cant put that try block there.  But maybe it's not really like that and what you posted is a simplification?